# Geb: Driver Creation Failed

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, groovy, geb

I wrote a very simple test automation script and it was just executing fine days back.
Today I relaunched the same test script without any modification and it is getting error like below:

```
Caught: geb.driver.DriverCreationException: failed to create driver from callback 'script146839...
```

**My code is below:**

```
Browser.drive {
to TopPage
report "HomePage"

loginButton.click()
report "LoginButtonClicked"
at LoginPage
report "AtLoginPage"

username.value("mymail")
password.value("mypass")
signin.click()  
at TopPage
report "AtHomePage" 

myPage.click()  
waitFor{at MyPage}
report "AtMyPage"
logout.click()  
waitFor{at BackToTopPage}
report "AtAfterLogoutPage"

goBackToTopPage.click()
```

}

Config file is below:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver 

    driver = { new FirefoxDriver() }    
    baseUrl = "http://www.xxx.co.jp"    
    reportsDir = "target/geb-reports"    
    waiting {
      timeout = 20
      retryInterval = 1.0
      includeCauseInMessage = true
    }    
    atCheckWaiting = true    
    baseNavigatorWaiting = true    
    encoding = 'SJIS'
```

I can not imagine suddenly what happened?

Comment: firefox auto-updated to an incompatible version?

Comment: I degraded to the version 46.0.1 which is the original but the same issue is there.

Comment: Can you past the whole stacktrace please?